# Chrome Extension. Modifying a changing URL?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

I'm just fiddling around with making a Chrome Extension because, why not? I was wondering how would I go about taking the last part of the url of a page *(which **changes** like a youtube video's url)* and replace it with something else when you click on the extension. If you could show the answer with all the files text that would be needed eg; *manifest.json* and anything else like a external JS file. Any help would be appreciated :)

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "test extension",
  "description": "Testing chrome extensions",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_title": "AYYYYYYYYYYYYYY"
  },

  "background":{
    "scripts":["background.js"]
  },

  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

This is all i have for the moment. I followed another article which used an external js file but I didn't know what to do with it from there. I'm trying to make a extension which when you are on a YouTube video you click the extension it takes the **watch?v=randomcharacters** and replaces it with another **watch?v=randomcharacters** or a specific video in my case. Doing this without just replacing the whole URL. Hopefully this extra info helps.

Comment: You should give us more information, otherwise we will not be able to help you. What do you want to do exactly? What have you tried? Could you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

See https://youtube.github.io/spfjs/ – specifically, its use of [`window.history`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history) `.pushState()` `.popState()` etc. etc. to manipulate the URL.

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
  code: 'window.history.pushState(null, window.title, window.location.href + "#!/")'
});
```

If you are triggering this from `chrome.browserAction.onClicked`, you should only need the [`activeTab`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) permission.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. How would I implement this code into my extension. Sorry for inconvenience